# Windows 10 Network Credentials not working

Tags: windows-10, networking, networkmanager, credentials

So, although connecting to our servers works from all other pc, including a VM that is running on my machine, for some reason my credentials won't work when i try to open a folder on our server.

I feel like i tried every conceivable way to fix it.

- I put the server ip and computer name before my username(with and
  wihtout all combination of backlashes)
- I put my windows log in into credentials
- I disabled creadential manager in services
- I added DWORD in registery
- I turned off and on every possible network option or windows feature pack on and off

I am really lost on what to do to fix it and would appreaciate any help.

I have windows 10 enterprise version 1909 installed if that, in case that helps.

Comment: What server? When you say "on the server" do you mean you're logged into a session on the server, or just using File Explorer? Have you checked the logs? Is this a business environment?

Comment: @music2myear I am just using file explorer. Yes it is a business environment. Which logs should i check?

Comment: Please add the exact text or a screenshot of the error message(s) you see when the connection fails. Are the computer, VM, and server all in the same domain? Can you connect to other folders or other servers? Check your windows system event logs for anything weird